# Value from Drop down in selenium without using select

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am in a situation where I have to select one value from the drop down, but I do not have any select class in my HTML code.

Code I have used so far

```
driver.findElement(By.id("unique value")).sendKeys("Add Claim Document");
```

Add Claim document is one of the drop down value. Please help

Comment: Can you consider showing us some of your work please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following xpath to solve your problem:

```
//*[contains(text(),'Add Claim Document')]
```

You can use it in your code as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Add Claim Document')]")).click();
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: tried your suggestion, but i think we have limitations in IE that it doesn't support XPATH and CSS locator.